Solving First Order Linear PDE's Using Seperation of Variables
been trying to figure out whether or not we are able to solve linear, semi-linear and quasi-linear PDE's using Separation of Variables instead of Characteristics. take for instance the PDE $u_x+xu_y=y$ with initial cauchy data of $u(0,y)=y$ which has a solution $u(x,y)=-\frac{x^3}{3}+xy+y-\frac{x^2}{2}$. I've tried a product solution of the form $u(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ which yields $f'(x)g(y)+xf(x)g'(y)=y$ but I'm not sure how to separate the variables from there. I've also tried a solution of the form $u(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ which yields $f'(x)+xg'(y)=y$ but again I'm not sure how to proceed or separate the variables, any tips would be helpful.
